# How do I stop a static cell refrence from changing, when adding a new row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, static, google-sheets-formula

I have a document I am using to calculate finances. I have the following **working** script that inserts a new row above row 2 pushing all data at row 2 and below down when cells A2:B2 are not blank.

```
function AddaLine() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [a2, b2] = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:B2").getDisplayValues()[0];
  if (a2 != "" && b2 != "") {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  }
}
```

Cell A1 contains:

```
=SUM($A$2:A3)
```

I want A2 to remain static but A3 to incriment as new rows are automatically added. The problem I'm having is the static cell reference is incrementing when a new row is added and becomes

```
=SUM($A$3:A4)
```

I want it to go to

```
=SUM($A$2:A4)
```

only incrementing the second, non-static, reference cell each time new rows are inserted above row 2.

```
$A$2:A5
$A$2:A6
$A$2:A7
...
$A$2:A5000
...
```

Any help figuring out what I assume is a simple issue that I can't wrap my head around would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I am trying to do this in such a way that the automation works in a cellphone app as well as PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `=SUM($A$2:A3)` try

```
=sum(offset(A3,-row(A3)+2,,row(A3)-1))
```

Comment: That 100% solved this issue! Thank you for your help! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` or `INDEX` could make a static reference:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A2"):A3)
```

OR

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,2):A3)
```